# Locally connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have read two definitions of a topological space $X$ being **locally connected at a point $x \in X$** , and want to prove they are equivalent.

Def.1 ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space#Definitions_and_first_examples)) A topological space $X$ is **locally connected at $x \in X$** if for every open set $U$ with $x \in U$ there exist an open connected set $V \subseteq U$ with $x \in V$

Def.2 ([wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/Local_Connectedness)) A topological space $X$ is **locally connected at $x \in X$** if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there exist a connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ with $V \subseteq U$.

---

I like more def.2 as it seems simplier without having to mention open sets, it just mention neighbourhoods.  Now I'll try to prove they are equivalent:

def.1 $\Rightarrow$ def.2) As every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains an open set $U'$ containing $x$, and by def.1 there is an open connected set $V' \subseteq U'$ with $x \in V'$ and $V = V'$ is a connected neighbourhood of $x$ with $V \subseteq U$.

def.2 $\Rightarrow$ def.1) (Here comes the problem)  Let $U$ be an open set with $x \in U$, so it is a neighbourhood of $x$, and by def.2 there exists $V \subseteq U$ connected with $x \in V$.  The problem is that $V$ could not be open.  As it is a neighbourhood of $x$, it contains at least one open subset $V' \subseteq$ with $x \in V'$.  But now $V'$ could not be connected.  I trying choosing the connected component $C_x$ of $V'$ that contains $x$.  I know that $C_x$ is closed, and connected, but I think it could be not open.  And I don't know what else to do.

Are these definitions really equivalent?  If yes I would appreciate any help finishing the proof, and if no I would appreciate a counterexample: A space $X$ with a point $x \in X$ that is def.2 but is not def.1

Comment: Wikipedia states that these two definitions are not equivalent. On the wikipedia page, the second is called "weakly locally connected at $x$", and they name an example at the very end of the article, "A certain infinite union of decreasing broom spaces is an example of a space which is weakly locally connected at a particular point, but not locally connected at that point." The corresponding global properties are equivalent (if a space is weakly locally connected at every point, then it is locally connected).

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit ashamed I didn't notice that (I didn't read about weakly locally connected as I thought that was another thing).  I agree with you that what the wiki calls weakly locally connected at $x$ is equivalent with my def.2.  But then I read weakly locally connected at $x$ in the wikibooks page and it seems equivalent to their own definition of locally connected at $x$ ''unless'' by neighbourhood they refer to open neighbourhood. Do you agree?